# Best way to formally test Windows Phone App upgrades

Tags: windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I have version 1 of my Windows Phone App (w8.0) in the store which has been running for a while now. The app uses a SQL Server compact database for local persistence on the device.

I'm now ready to release v2 of my app (w8.1), which has a number of database schema changes. The question is how I can formally setup a test environment for the test team where testers can:

1...Install v1 of the app from the store

2...Run it up and do some light activity

3...Then upgrade the app on the phone to v2

4...Continue testing using an upgraded version of the database

Up to now all v2 testing has been done using a shiney new install of the app.

I know i can do this using Visual Studio, but this defeats the objective of the test i.e. a live user upgrading via the store.

I've tried using the app deployment tool, but this deletes v1 of the app (including the database) when it deploys v2. I was surprised it did this - I thought it would recognise the install as an upgrade. I can verify this because it deletes the database. I am using the same names/keys in the manifest, including an incremented version number.

For now I have a new (hidden) TEST app in the store where i've submitted v1 of the app. Once the testers are ready, I submit v2 of the app to the store which the testers then upgrade. Problem here is that it takes upwards of 12 hours for the store to publish the upgraded version.

I am aware that you can install an app from the SD cards, which is pretty close. Has anyone else found a good elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use **Windows Phone Power Tools** to achieve this.
Here's the link: https://wptools.codeplex.com

Just install the old xap, do some stuff and then update to the new xap using the "UPDATE" button. If you don't change the app ID, it will surely work.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you for this (+1) . It does indeed work and appears to overcome the short comings of the deployment tools included with VS. Unfortunately it only covers development apps (not ones installed via the store), so it doesn't allow me to test an upgrade of an app installed via the store. The ideal solution would be to have 2 separate app store submissions i.e. v1 and v2, where installing v2 updates v1 rather than installing a whole new app (you are left with the app on the phone twice).

Comment: When your app gets published, the Application ID is automatically changed during the submission. You just have to retrieve the AppID from the Dev Center (click on the app, go to "View app identity details" under App management and copy the URL for WP 8.1, the id is the part after "http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=") and replace it in Visual Studio (in WMAppManifest.xaml), in this way your Store app will be replaced by the deployed one.